# How to make UserControl fullscreen in UWP?

Tags: user-controls, uwp, fullscreen, mediaelement

I have Usercontrol (named MyControl)

```
<Grid Background="White">
        <MediaElement Name="Player"></MediaElement>
        <Button Name="btnFullscreen" 
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Fullscreen"></Button>
</Grid>
```

and MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:MyControl></local:MyControl>
</Grid>
```

I want to click "btnFullscreen" to make "MyControl" fullscreen like you toggle the fullscreen mode in every video player, in fullscreen mode have "btnFullscreen" and "Player"

Sorry, I speak English not very well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the MediaElement Control to fullscreen mode by following codes:

```
private void btnFullscreen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    Player.IsFullWindow = true;
}
```

And MyControl.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement Name="Player"  AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" >
    </MediaElement>
    <Button Name="btnFullscreen" 
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Content="Fullscreen" Click="btnFullscreen_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**Update:** If you want to reate new Video Player with new player control like play button, volume slider, fullscreen button, slider and so on. I suggest you following the steps of this document: [Create custom media transport control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls). And you can find a way to add fullscreen button to your Video Player  by ***Adding a custom button*** section of this document. Here is the official sample of custom media transport control: [XamlCustomMediaTransportControls](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlCustomMediaTransportControls).

Comment: If I use "Player.IsFullWindow = true", "Player" don't show "btnFullscreen" in screen. I want to create new Video Player with new player control like play button, volume slider, fullscreen button, slider ...
Thank you!

Comment: If you want to create your own Video Player, I suggest you creating  a custom media transport control and add the full screen button as a custom button of this control. Please check the update of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it :)